# How should I work with arrays of nibbles/quarter-bytes?

Tags: c++, arrays, std, nibble

I find myself needing to work with "arrays" of elements of size 1/2 , or 1/4 - i.e. "arrays" of nibbles or quarter-bytes, packed together within bytes (according to some endianness choice).

I know the standard library has the (unfortunate?) `std::vector<bool>` specialization (and Boost has `dynamic_bitset`), but I want an abstraction better fitting my actual element sizes rather than individual bits. If push comes to shove I may implement a pseudo-container with proxy objects, but I would rather avoid having to do that myself if there's a reasonable alternative. Is there? Specifically, does the standard library has any relevant facility I could use?

Note: We're talking longer arrays whose length is not known at compile time.

Comment: No, there's nothing in the standard library.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: So you'd say roll-your-own?

Comment: Yes. Or, of course, pay someone else to do it for you.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: I'm not that kind of rich, or lazy...